# Removing Mathias' dotfiles settings

Tags: macos, terminal

Just installed [Mathias' dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles) but I didn't like some features of it. Especially executing `./.osx` command. For example it's changing dock icons' sizes, removing TimeMachine icons (i'm using it frequently), changing locale settings etc.

How can I revert **all** settings to default ones, remove all dotfiles settings.

After this I'll for the dotfiles project and make my own dotfiles based on Mathias' project.

Comment: Simply remove all `.*` files  from `$HOME` dir except: `.CFUserTextEncoding` and `.DS_Store`.

Comment: But **.osx** file changed some settings with `defaults write ...` command . Deleting files won't affect settings ?

Comment: Ah You are right I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple command to revert everything to default.

Depending on the number of installed apps besides Apple's own standard apps, it's probably faster to reinstall OS X or restore a backup.

.osx alone modifies about 200 settings - assuming one mod per 4 lines.

Next time better use a hypervisor like VMware or Virtual Box, set up your preferred OS X in a VM and test dotfiles using the snapshot feature.

Comment: Well, I'll try to revert them in *hardcore way* . I'll modify .osx file and replace all *true* strings with *false* settings. And check all settings one by one.

Comment: @Eray I’d `defaults delete` instead and let the system restore the default settings. https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/issues/190

Comment: I'll upgrade my system from Yosemite to El Capitan , Will this upgrade fix my problems too? @MathiasBynens

Comment: @Eray - no as it will not chnage any files in your home directory so all the  script chnages will stay

Comment: But won't it change all default settings (which affected by **.osx** file) to El Capitan defaults ?

Comment: @Eray Only if you perform a clean install.